# Отправка почты с сервера, не оправляется на Gmail

Tags: linux, sendmail, gmail, postfix, phpmailer

Дело в том что у меня есть один домен devdomain.com и все сайты я создаю на нем как субдомены: site1.devdomain.com, site2.devdomain.com...

При отправки письма на любую Gmail почту получаю вот такую ошибку:

> Reporting-MTA: dns; srv-115.devdomain.com
>
> X-Postfix-Queue-ID: F2CFEA1248
>
> X-Postfix-Sender: rfc820; site1support@devdomain.com
>
> Arrival-Date: Tue, 25 Dec 2018 19:26:44 -0500 (EST)
>
> Final-Recipient: rfc820; randomuser77@gmail.com
>
> Original-Recipient: rfc820;randomuser77@gmail.com
>
> Action: failed
>
> Status: 5.7.1
>
> Remote-MTA: dns; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
>
> Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.7.1 **This
>   message does not have authentication
>       information or fails to pass 550-5.7.1 authentication checks. To best
>       protect our users from spam, the 550-5.7.1 message has been *blocked*.** Please
>       visit 550-5.7.1
>       https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550
>       5.7.1 information. g21-v6si29470507ljh.116 - gsmtp

Как мне кажется дело в том, что отправка идет с субдомена и Google блокирует всё, что идет оттуда.

**Вопрос:** есть какие-то варианты доставить письмо с субдомена на gmail?

Comment: Думаю, надо начать с выполнения этого: Keep valid reverse DNS records your IP address that point to your domain. Ну и вообще, почитать по указанной ссылке. Там много полезного.

Comment: SPF, DKIM, DMARC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогла установка и настройка `opendkim`

Answer (score 1):

У нас была такая проблема из-за несоответствия PTR DNS записи. Для исправления обращались к Ростелекому

Comment: Не подскажете, какие были несоответствия в PTR DNS записи?